# how to make radio button sticky with the result?

Tags: php, radio-button

My radio button worked good(can stored data into database) but I want to make my radio button sticky with the result even after I refresh it. Can anyone help me? This is my code right now:

```
if($showtt == 1) {$slect="[Ya]";} else { $slect="[Tidak]";}

Print "<tr><td ><b>Jadual di\"hide\"? </b><i>$slect</i></td>"

if ( $showtt == 1 ) 
  $sel="checked";
else
  $sel="";


echo "
  <td>: <input type=radio Name=v5 Option Value=1 checked='checked' $sel>Ya
    <br>: <input type=radio Name=v5 Option Value=0 checked='checked' $sel>Tidak

</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: just you need to remove `checked='checked'` from your input

Answer (score 0):

Replace your echo statement with this one:

```
echo "<td>:
<input type=radio name=v5 Option value=1 $showtt == 1 ? 'checked : NULL>Ya
<br>: <input type=radio name=v5 Option value=0 $showtt != 1 ? 'checked : NULL>Tidak

</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: still not working. If i replace echo statement with this my radio button does not check.  I want to make my radio button sticky with the result even after I refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `checked='checked'` from your code Use below echo statement.

```
echo "
  <td>: <input type=radio Name=v5 Option Value=1 $sel>Ya
    <br>: <input type=radio Name=v5 Option Value=0 $sel>Tidak

</td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: I remove  checked='checked' from my code but still does not work.

Comment: sorry, it work.. my mistake. I remove at onother code file..tq